# Why will my items not delete in my text based game after they are picked up?

Tags: python

I am creating a text based adventure game for one of my college courses. I need to be able to move through the rooms, pick up all the items, and get to the 'Boss' room to finish the game. So far I am able to move through rooms, pick up items, exit the game, and finish the game when all items are collected. However, once the items are picked up, they do not delete from the room, and still show that the items are in the rooms. I have looked through similar questions, but it seems that others have written their code differently than I have and their solutions don't really help with my problem.

```
rooms = {  # create dictionary with list of rooms
    'Center of the Village': {'go north': "Village Scribe", 'go south': "Mage Tower", 'go east': 'Village Dining Hall',
                              'go west': 'Village Tailor', 'item': 'Nothing'},
    'Village Scribe': {'go east': 'Bridge to the Castle', 'go south': 'Center of the Village', 'item': 'The Monster '
                                                                                                       'Hunting '
                                                                                                       'Guidebook'},
    'Mage Tower': {'go north': 'Center of the Village', 'go east': 'Mage Library', 'item': 'The Magic Staff'},
    'Village Dining Hall': {'go north': 'Village Elders', 'go west': 'Center of the Village', 'item': 'The Hearty Stew'
                            },
    'Village Tailor': {'go east': 'Center of the Village', 'item': 'The Magic Cloak'},
    'Village Elders': {'go south': 'Village Dining Hall', 'item': 'The Amulet of Protection'},
    'Mage Library': {'go west': 'Mage Tower', 'item': 'The Spell Caster Scrolls'},
    'Bridge to the Castle': {'go west': 'Village Scribe', 'item': 'The Bridge Troll'}
}


def main_menu():  # create main menu prompt when game is launched
    print('---------------------------')
    print("*** Magicians Adventure Text Game ***\n")
    print("You Must Collect All Six Magic Items To Defeat The Bridge Troll\n")
    print("Movement Commands: \n"
          "\nType: 'go' Followed by: 'north', 'south', 'east', or 'west' to move through the village. "
          "\nType: 'grab' to pick up an item. "
          "\nType: 'exit' to end the game.")
    input('\nPress Enter to continue...\n---------------------------\n')
    return "Good Luck!"


def show_status():  # indicate room and inventory contents
    print('\n-------------------------')
    print('You are at the {}'.format(current_room))
    print('In this space you see {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    print('-------------------------------')


print(main_menu())  # print main menu for player
print()

current_room = 'Center of the Village'  # starting room for player

commands = ['go north', 'go south', 'go east', 'go west', 'exit', 'grab']  # valid movements

inventory = []  # creates a list for items in inventory


def move_rooms(current_room, directions):  # define the movement sequence between rooms
    current_room = rooms[current_room]
    new_room = current_room[directions]
    return new_room  # use return function to apply new location


while True:

    show_status()

    if current_room == 'Bridge to the Castle':

        if len(inventory) < 6:
            print('You Did Not Have Enough Magic Power! \nYou have been crushed by the Troll!!!')
            break
        else:
            print('You Have Slain The Bridge Troll!!! \nYou Are Victorious!!!')
            break

    direction_input = input('What is your move? \n \n> ')
    print('\n--------------------------')

    moves = rooms[current_room]

    if current_room == 'Center of the Village':
        if direction_input == 'grab':
            print('There are no items here...')

    if direction_input == 'exit':  # use if statement with exit as key input and break
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        print('---------------------------')
        break
    # add in the below if and elif for valid and not valid moves from the player

    if direction_input in rooms[current_room]:

        current_room = move_rooms(current_room, direction_input)

    elif direction_input not in commands:
        print('Invalid move.\n')
        print('---------------------------\n')

    elif direction_input not in rooms[current_room]:

        print(f'You can not go that way.')
        print('---------------------------\n')

    if direction_input == 'grab':

        if rooms[current_room]['item'] not in inventory:

            inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])

    elif rooms[current_room]['item'] in inventory:

        del rooms[current_room]['item']
```

Comment: Please use the following references to assist you in debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error in your code is that you are not changing the item description in the room once an item was picked up. As a result, even after an item was collected, the room's description remained indicated that it was present. Confusion resulted from the disparity between the real item state and the displayed description.

you can modify your show_status() function to update the room's item description when an item is picked up.

```
rooms = {.....}
def grab_item(item):  # function to pick up items
    if rooms[current_room]['item'] == item:
        inventory.append(item)
        print(f'You picked up {item}.')
        rooms[current_room]['item'] = 'Nothing'
    else:
        print(f'{item} is not available in this room.')

# Modify show_status() to display the correct item description
def show_status():
    print('\n-------------------------')
    print('You are at the {}'.format(current_room))
    print('In this space you see {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    print('-------------------------------')

# Main game loop
current_room = 'Center of the Village'
inventory = []
main_menu()

while True:
    show_status()
    move = input('\nWhat would you like to do? ').lower().split()

    if move[0] == 'go':
        if move[1] in rooms[current_room]:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][move[1]]
        else:
            print('You cannot go that way.')
    elif move[0] == 'grab':
        grab_item(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    elif move[0] == 'exit':
        print('Thank you for playing!')
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid command.')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to delete the 'item' right after the player grabs it and aditionally add another conditional into the 'grab' if statement.

```
if direction_input == 'grab':
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room] and rooms[current_room]['item'] not in inventory:
        if rooms[current_room]['item'] != 'Nothing':
            inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
        del rooms[current_room]['item']
```

And should delete the unneeded statement below it :

```
 elif rooms[current_room]['item'] in inventory:
     del rooms[current_room]['item']
```

And also you need to check whether the 'item' object present in the current_room or not where you use it :

```
def show_status():  # indicate room and inventory contents

    item = rooms[current_room]['item'] if 'item' in rooms[current_room] else 'Noting'

    print('\n-------------------------')
    print('You are at the {}'.format(current_room))
    print('In this space you see {}'.format(item))
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    print('-------------------------------')
```

I checked it and seems like it's working after these changes applied.

Comment: Your code is broken. Read my answer to understand why.

Comment: I fixed the borken part.

Comment: No you didn't. It's still broken in `show_status` and your `show_status` is not properly indented.

Comment: You literally added nearly the same thing what i did in show_status to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to fix:

- change `'The Monster ' 'Hunting ' 'Guidebook'` to `'The Monster Hunting Guidebook'` in `rooms` variable
- remove `'item': 'Nothing'` (otherwise you can grab `Nothing`) from `rooms` variable
- replace `print('In this space you see {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))` with `print(f"In this space you see {rooms[current_room].get('item', 'nothing')}")`
- add `del rooms[current_room]['item']` to remove item when you grab it
- remove last `elif` section (doesn't make sense)

Updated code:

```
rooms = {  # create dictionary with list of rooms
    'Center of the Village': {'go north': "Village Scribe", 'go south': "Mage Tower", 'go east': 'Village Dining Hall', 'go west': 'Village Tailor'},
    'Village Scribe': {'go east': 'Bridge to the Castle', 'go south': 'Center of the Village', 'item': 'The Monster Hunting Guidebook'},
    'Mage Tower': {'go north': 'Center of the Village', 'go east': 'Mage Library', 'item': 'The Magic Staff'},
    'Village Dining Hall': {'go north': 'Village Elders', 'go west': 'Center of the Village', 'item': 'The Hearty Stew'
                            },
    'Village Tailor': {'go east': 'Center of the Village', 'item': 'The Magic Cloak'},
    'Village Elders': {'go south': 'Village Dining Hall', 'item': 'The Amulet of Protection'},
    'Mage Library': {'go west': 'Mage Tower', 'item': 'The Spell Caster Scrolls'},
    'Bridge to the Castle': {'go west': 'Village Scribe', 'item': 'The Bridge Troll'}
}


def main_menu():  # create main menu prompt when game is launched
    print('---------------------------')
    print("*** Magicians Adventure Text Game ***\n")
    print("You Must Collect All Six Magic Items To Defeat The Bridge Troll\n")
    print("Movement Commands: \n"
          "\nType: 'go' Followed by: 'north', 'south', 'east', or 'west' to move through the village. "
          "\nType: 'grab' to pick up an item. "
          "\nType: 'exit' to end the game.")
    input('\nPress Enter to continue...\n---------------------------\n')
    return "Good Luck!"


def show_status():  # indicate room and inventory contents
    print('\n-------------------------')
    print('You are at the {}'.format(current_room))
    print(f"In this space you see {rooms[current_room].get('item', 'nothing')}")
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    print('-------------------------------')


print(main_menu())  # print main menu for player
print()

current_room = 'Center of the Village'  # starting room for player

commands = ['go north', 'go south', 'go east', 'go west', 'exit', 'grab']  # valid movements

inventory = []  # creates a list for items in inventory


def move_rooms(current_room, directions):  # define the movement sequence between rooms
    current_room = rooms[current_room]
    new_room = current_room[directions]
    return new_room  # use return function to apply new location


while True:

    show_status()

    if current_room == 'Bridge to the Castle':

        if len(inventory) < 6:
            print('You Did Not Have Enough Magic Power! \nYou have been crushed by the Troll!!!')
            break
        else:
            print('You Have Slain The Bridge Troll!!! \nYou Are Victorious!!!')
            break

    direction_input = input('What is your move? \n \n> ')
    print('\n--------------------------')

    moves = rooms[current_room]

    if current_room == 'Center of the Village':
        if direction_input == 'grab':
            print('There are no items here...')

    if direction_input == 'exit':  # use if statement with exit as key input and break
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        print('---------------------------')
        break
    # add in the below if and elif for valid and not valid moves from the player

    if direction_input in rooms[current_room]:

        current_room = move_rooms(current_room, direction_input)

    elif direction_input not in commands:
        print('Invalid move.\n')
        print('---------------------------\n')

    elif direction_input not in rooms[current_room]:

        print(f'You can not go that way.')
        print('---------------------------\n')

    if direction_input == 'grab':

        if rooms[current_room].get('item'):

            inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
            del rooms[current_room]['item']
```